# How to get value of a textfield during UITest in Xcode 7?

Tags: macos, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to test a simple Celsius Fahrenheit Converter on a Mac. I'm running macOS Sierra and Xcode 7.2.1.

[image]

When I run the following test

```
- (void)testExample2 {
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    XCUIElement *cfWindow = app.windows[@"Celsius Fahrenheit Converter"];

    XCUIElement *textField1 = [[cfWindow childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField]elementBoundByIndex:0];

    XCUIElement *textField2 = app.textFields[@"fahrField"];

    [textField1 typeText:@"21\r"];

    NSString *str = (NSString *) textField2.value;

    XCTAssertEqual(str, @"69.8");
}
```

I am basically entering value 21 in the Celsius field and expect to get value 69.8 in the Fahrenheit field. But I get the error message

**test failure: -[CFConverterUITests testExample2] failed: ((str) equal to (@"69.8")) failed: ("<4536392e 38000000>") is not equal to ("<30c15800 01000000>")**

Does anyone know what is wrong and what to do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCTAssertEqual doesn't work on objects. Your assertion should be as `XCTAssert([str isEqualToString:@"69.8"]);`